# Visual Studio 2015 now moves members to new line

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, code-formatting

When we need to use a backing field for a property, we have a practice of combining the backing field with the property it goes to:

```
public int MyProperty
{
    get { return _MyProperty; }
    set { _MyProperty = value; }
} private int _MyProperty;
```

We prefer this greatly to a long list of of member variables at the top for many reasons.

1. You don't have to scroll up and down, you see it all right there.
2. Variable doesn't get left on refactor when property is removed.
3. When copy and pasting things around, you never forget to bring the member variable along.

The problem:

Visual Studio is now moving the member variable to the next line when we Press Ctrl E + D or choose Edit | Advanced | Format Document.

```
public int MyProperty
{
    get { return _MyProperty; }
    set { _MyProperty = value; }
} 
private int _MyProperty;
```

I have played with the Tools | Options | Text Editor | C# | Formatting | New Lines section.

Anyone have any idea how to make visual studio stop moving the member variable to a new line?

FYI, I have Resharper.

Comment: when does it move the member to a new line?

Comment: When I press Ctrl E + D or Edit | Advanced | Format Document.

Comment: If you don't adhere to standard formatting, don't use formatting helpers ;)

Comment: this doesnt happen for me btw ... ie your original format stays intact with `Ctrl E, D`

Comment: Try enabling in Tools->Options Text Editor->C#->Formatting->Wrapping->Leave statements and member declaration on the same line.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question directly, but with Resharper you can move a line of code up or down really quickly with Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Up/Down. It's super fast to move code, I use it all the time!

Comment: Ugh. I spent an hour toggling every settings. Nothing worked so far.

Comment: @wal, this doesn't happen to me in 2013 but it happens on 2015. Are you on 2015?

Comment: i was on 2013 and just tried it in 2015 and yep what you describe does occur

Comment: Since this seems to be an problem without a configuration option, I've submitted a bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2458080

Answer (score 0):

I think this option is probably causing a problem for you:

[image]

Enable `Leave statements and members declaration on the same line`

Comment: Drats! It didn't fix it.

Comment: Try also with options under brackets section. Because you have that before your statement, it could be that some option there forces the backing field to move to the next line.

Answer (score -1):

Or (of course)

```
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

is the preferred style these days (syntactic sugar, same end code).

Comment: Of course we use this if we don't need a backing field. I am talking about when we *do* require a backing field.

Comment: Ah, sorry - example wasn't clear (didn't look like you needed the backing field).